# Predict next date based on previous frequency in a time-series

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series

I have a data frame that looks like the one bellow. The data frame has more features but I only show this for simplification purposes.

```
    CODE    DATE        IND_AVG_MONTH_REC     IND_STD_MONTH_REC 
0   15295   2021-01-22  0.375                 0.382733
1   15801   2020-12-04  0.125                 0.309359
2   23369   2021-01-01  0.750                 0.216506
```

The AVG and STD are the mean and standard deviation per month of each COD.
The DATE is the last time the user had activity.
I want to predict the next date based on the the AVG and the last date.

For this I did a linear regression and got the predicted frequency. I am happy with the results because they have a small error from the predicted to the test sets. (All values are integers or floats)

```
# Not all features fom the data set were used
X = df[['IND_MIN_REC_VAL', 'IND_TOTAL_TERM_CALL_QTY', 'IND_TOTAL_ORIG_CALL', 'IND_VAL_LAST_REC', 'OLD', 'IND_SMS_QTY', 'IND_TOTAL_SMS_QTY', 'IND_MIN_REC_QTY_DAY', 'IND_TOTAL_GPRS_QTY', 'IND_GPRS_QTY', 'IND_AVG_MONTH_GPRS_QTY', 'IND_AVG_MONTH_SMS', 'IND_STD_MONTH_SMS', 'IND_STD_MONTH_GPRS_QTY', 'IND_QTD_LAST_REC', 'COD_TAR', 'COD_CART', 'IND_TERM_CALL_QTY', 'IND_MAX_REC_VAL', 'IND_AVG_TERM_CALL_DUR', 'IND_STD_TERM_CALL_DUR', 'IND_ORIG_CALL_QTY', 'IND_AVG_MONTH_TERM_CALL', 'IND_STD_MONTH_TERM_CALL', 'IND_MAX_REC_QTY_DAY', 'IND_AVG_ORIG_CALL_DUR', 'IND_STD_ORIG_CALL_DUR', 'IND_AVG_MONTH_PRIG_CALL', 'IND_STD_ORIG_CALL', 'IND_AVG_GPRS_DUR', 'IND_STD_GPRS_DUR', 'IND_STD_MONTH_REC_VAL', 'IND_STD_MONTH_REC', 'IND_AVG_MONTH_REC_VAL']]
y = df['IND_AVG_MONTH_REC']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

model = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)

y_preds = model.predict((X_test))
```

And then calculated error metrics and got the following which I am happy with:

```
MAE: 0.11467427514645877
MSE: 0.03279457004316404
RMSE: 0.1810927111817702
```

How do I get the next (predicted) date seeing I have the predicted frequency already?

Is there a way to enter the last date and predicted frequency and get the next date in python/pandas?

Comment: Since you haven't shown any code, it would be hard to help you.  Please post the minimum code needed to reproduce the model and perhaps someone will chime in with an answer.

Comment: Hi, just edited with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are running into the problem of using linear regression to try and solve a time-series problem.

Imagine predicting housing prices.  We can know the number of bedrooms, if it has a garage, the size of the yard, the current interest rates, current unemployment rate, the number of houses currently on the market, etc.  Ultimately we will get a good prediction.

Now imagine you want to predict the house price 6 months into the future.  You still know the number of bedrooms, and if it has a garage, but you don't know the future interest rates, unemployment rates, or how many houses will be on the market.

You can either estimate these using your own best guess (perhaps use a range for best/worst scenarios and let the person using the model decide which to use) or you could use a time-series modeling approach and use it to predict forward 6 months by learning what today's patterns mean for the future.

Comment: You are sugesting changing into a model such as ARIMA, GARCH or LSTM for example and neglect the regression for predicting the next date?
Is there any link/post or book you recommend reading?
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Peter I'm suggesting looking at both and determining what works best for you.  You can google how to set up time series models there are a bunch of great tutorials out there.

Comment: I then actually realised I can very simply get the next date with the data I showed ahahah
But I will also look at analysis through time-series models. For what I understand the way I did requires a bit more pre processing since the time series algotrithms, for the end result I want, need more refining. But thank you for your answer!